# the correct usage of verbs"lie" and "lay"

Tags: verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

She wanna lay in bed or she wanna lie in bed.. Which one is correct.. Because in many English songs I have heard lay instead of lie..  Could anyone please clear this.

Comment: It seems that Americans use the word *lay* when British people would use the word *lie*.

Comment: You would say "She wants to lie in bed" if you want to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

In songwriting, the sound and the evocativeness of the words used is much more important than using proper grammar.

Here's an explanation of lay vs lie:
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/lay-versus-lie

Comment: thank you.. i got the difference..... If you don't mind please tell me, is this sentence wrong- I had got your message in the morning.. Or is it I got your message in the morning.. I have a confusion in past and past perfect... Looking forward to getting a clear cut difference so that I remember them...

Comment: "had got" is not technically correct in that usage, though it's used a lot in some places. "I got your message" or "by the time you called me, I had listened to it"

Comment: @roopa since this is a site for language and grammar enthusiasts, I feel I need to point out that you might be using a tad more full stops than is strictly necessary. End your sentences with `.` not `..`, certainly not `....` and not `...` unless you [mean to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis).

Comment: I wouldn't say more *important*. I would just say more *common*. Nothing is more important than proper grammar, but this is just my opinion. :-)

Comment: Tyler, I understand your point of view, but doubt you are a songwriter. From a listener's standpoint, most songs contain at least one grammatical error and would be diminished were the errors fixed. If you were to contend that Satisfaction would have been a better song id Mick Jagger had sung "I can't get any satisfaction," then I would strenuously disagree.